# How to get ftp error from System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, ftp-client, ftpwebrequest

How to get the ftp server error when handling an System.Net.WebException?

Status field only report an Protocol error for most errors like login failure.

For context, the following client code as an example:

```
try {
    FtpWebRequest request = 
      (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mars/test.htm");  
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;  

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);  
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());  

    reader.Close();  
    response.Close();    
}    
catch (WebException ex)
{
   //get the server error
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Response is actually an `FtpWebResponse`. By casting `ex.Response` to `FtpWebResponse`, I can get access to server error through `StatusCode`.

Example:

```
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
       var ftpResponse = ex.Response as FtpWebResponse;                      
       log.Error(ftpResponse.StatusCode); //as enumerate
       log.Error((int)ftpResponse.StatusCode); //as integer
  }
```